# Is it possible to launch a vscode extension with a set of custom settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension, and while testing it out I've hit a bit of a snag. Some functionality depends on custom settings that I define in the `configuration` of `package.json`. I would like to be able to launch a new VSCode window with the settings set to particular values, but I can't find how to do that.

What I have in `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "ns.customSetting": "customValue"
        },
        {
            "name": "Extension with another value",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--disable-extensions",
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "ns.customSetting": "anotherValue"
        }
    ]
}
```

That hasn't been working, but hopefully the idea is clear. I want that new window to open with the custom setting already set to the value I want. How do I do that?

Comment: Could `configurationDefaults` work for your use case? https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.configurationDefaults

Comment: AFAIK, `configurationDefaults` only lives in package.json. I do have a value there, but it doesn't let me have multiple configs, each of which would launch a window with a different value for the custom setting.